# Update Database From Multi-Table Bound DataGridView Without Changing Rows

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2000

I have a DataGridView that contains data from multiple databases. All but three of the columns are ReadOnly. The three editable columns are all from the same table and that is the only table that needs to be edited via the DGV.

The following is the update procedure I'm using to save changes made in the DGV:

```
Public Sub UpdateScheduleData()
    Try
        If IgnoreInput Then Exit Sub

        Conn = GetConnect()
        Conn.Open()

        cmdSQL = New SqlCommand("Update Orders_Open Set JobStartDate = @JobStartDate, JobCompleteDate = @JobCompleteDate, LoadDate = @LoadDate, Status = @Status Where OrderID = @OrderID", daSchedule.SelectCommand.Connection)

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@OrderID", SqlDbType.VarChar))
        cmdSQL.Parameters("@OrderID").Value = dgSchedule.Rows(LastEditedRow).Cells("Order ID").Value.ToString

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@JobStartDate", SqlDbType.VarChar))
        If dgSchedule.Rows(LastEditedRow).Cells("Job Start").Value.ToString <> "" Then
            cmdSQL.Parameters("@JobStartDate").Value = dgSchedule.Rows(LastEditedRow).Cells("Job Start").Value.ToString
        Else
            cmdSQL.Parameters("@JobStartDate").Value = DBNull.Value
        End If

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@JobCompleteDate", SqlDbType.VarChar))
        If dgSchedule.Rows(LastEditedRow).Cells("Job Complete").Value.ToString <> "" Then
            cmdSQL.Parameters("@JobCompleteDate").Value = dgSchedule.Rows(LastEditedRow).Cells("Job Complete").Value.ToString
        Else
            cmdSQL.Parameters("@JobCompleteDate").Value = DBNull.Value
        End If

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LoadDate", SqlDbType.VarChar))
        If dgSchedule.Rows(LastEditedRow).Cells("Load Date").Value.ToString <> "" Then
            cmdSQL.Parameters("@LoadDate").Value = dgSchedule.Rows(LastEditedRow).Cells("Load Date").Value.ToString
        Else
            cmdSQL.Parameters("@LoadDate").Value = DBNull.Value
        End If

        daSchedule.UpdateCommand = cmdSQL
        daSchedule.Update(dtSchedule)
        Conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Source & ": " & ex.Message, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        LogErrors(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString & " -- " & ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

I have tried calling this procedure from several different events, but the only one that seems to work properly is the RowValidated event that occurs when I click on a different row in the database. This isn't very user friendly because the use will often want to set dates and immediately print a work order that reflects those dates. Having to click on another order and then back to the order they're trying to work with is inconvenient and shouldn't be necessary.

However, every other event I've tried (CellEndEdit, CellValidated, CellLeave, etc), the update doesn't go through to the database. I've set a break at `daSchedule.Update(dtSchedule)` and the datatable always reflects the correct data, but nothing changes in the database.

For the record, LastEditedRow is set in the CellBeginEdit event using `LastEditedRow = dgSchedule.CurrentRow.Index`. I've stepped through the UpdateScheduleData procedure several times and the values being added to the parameters are always correct, no exceptions ever occur, the database simply fails to update when the DataAdapter.Update command is executed, unless the user has clicked on another row.

What am I doing wrong that prevents the database update from occurring even though the datatable is displaying the correct data?